# Instagram Create Account API?

Tags: facebook, instagram, registration

I've been trying to use this URL that apparently creates an Instagram account.
However, it returns asking for my login. I thought you didn't have to have an account to register the account, no?

```
http://instagram.com/api/v2/push/register/?platform=XXX&device_type=XXX
```

Returns:

> {"status":"fail","message":"login_required"}

If this is the login to Facebook, is there another API that registers using your phone number or email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think account creation is publicly supported via the API. Besides please note that:

> Instagram Platform and documentation update. Apps created on or after
>   Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated
>   API rate-limits and behaviors. Prior to going Live, and being able to
>   be used by people other than the developers of the app, these apps
>   will have to go through a new review process. Please read the API
>   documentation or the Change Log for more details.
>
> Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until
>   June 2016. After June 2016, the app will automatically be moved to
>   Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process. The
>   previous version of our documentation is still available here.

Source: https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

That URL is part of the login flow of the Instagram private **API**, the one that the Instagram App uses internally. The login flow consists of multiple requests to the Instagram **API** endpoints, In the recent versions it is:

```
            # POST /api/v1/qe/sync/
            # POST /api/v1/launcher/sync/
            # GET /api/v1/zr/token/result/
            # GET /api/v1/multiple_accounts/get_account_family/
            # GET /api/v1/banyan/banyan/
            # POST /api/v1/feed/reels_tray/
            # POST /api/v1/feed/timeline/
            # POST /api/v1/push/register/  
            # POST /api/v1/push/register/
            # POST /api/v1/push/register/
            # POST /api/v1/ads/graphql/
            # GET /api/v1/media/blocked/
            # GET /api/v1/news/inbox/
            # GET /api/v1/loom/fetch_config/
            ....
```

with the corresponding `headers`, **cookies** and signed `body/params` depending on the method of the request